# Object Oriented mode of cleaning dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, dataframe, oop

I need help writing my python code in Object Oriented mode. I am trying to flag column values in a dataframe using pandas. Can someone help me how I should get started or refer me to some resources? How can I declare a global variable and specify the range for Temperature and Humidity and then write a function to flag the values falling outside of the range?

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd


filename = 'data.csv'
#Read the dataframe and display the column names in the dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', encoding="Latin",low_memory=False, keep_default_na = False, parse_dates = True)


#Condition: If the values are less than -50 and greater than 50, flag the values

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if (row['Temperature'] < -50) | (row['Temperature (C)'] > 50):
            print index, row ['Temperature']


#Condition: If the values are less than 0 and greater than 100, flag the values

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if (row['Humidity'] < 0.0) | (row['Humidity'] > 100):
        print index, row ['Humidity']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display the rows sastifying some conditions you can use the query method.

```
print df.query('Temperature < -50 | Temperature > 50')
```

If you want to add a flag in a new column then use df.eval

```
# init the new column
df['Flag']= 'Inside'

# update based on the test 
df.loc[df.eval('Temperature < -50 | Temperature > 50'), 'Flag'] = 'Outside'
```